# Reuse Skillsets in multiple Azure Cognitive Search Resources

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I developed a custom skillset that is called by an indexer within an Azure Cognitive Search Resource. It is possible to reuse this custom skillset with multiple indexers that are defined *in a single Azure Cognitive Search Resource.*

Is it possible to call that same skillset from an indexer that is *in a different Azure Search Service Resource?*

The [MSFT Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/skillset-operations) say that 'As a high-level resource, you can design a skillset once, and then reference it in multiple indexers.' - but it is unclear to me if or how you would reuse the skillset with an indexer that is in a different Azure Search Service Resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-use the same skillset definition, but you'll need to create a new skillset instance for the other search service.

Comment: both answers are useful - but this is the answer to the intent behind my question. you have to create a new skillset for each service. can't call across services. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can take the json definition of your skillset, and reuse it with multiple indexers in the same service, or in an indexer in a different service.

Here's an example of how I've done this at https://github.com/liamca/covid19search/tree/master/AzureCognitiveSearchService.  This folder contains a Jupyter notebook to set up a Cognitive Search service, and the various pieces (skillset, indexer, index, etc.) are stored as .json and reused each time that you create a service.

If you typically use the Azure portal "Import data" experience, there isn't an easy way to use your skillset json during that workflow.  So you could just select a single skill during "Import data", and after the "Import data" wizard is completed, then click on the skillset that was created with a single skill, and paste your custom skillset into that Skillset Definition (JSON) and click "Save".

Comment: Or you can use the REST API or SDK and automate it.